# how caching via nginx result of prerender.io

Tags: angularjs, caching, nginx, prerender

We have site with frontend on angular that need to render for search bots and other application like skype, which can make preview of page.
We use nginx, which setup for proxing requests from bots to prerender, which installed on our server. But in that case prerendering one of page takes about 15 seconds.

So, question is how setup caching result of prerender?

I have already try:
put settings for caching into frontend.conf

```
proxy_cache_path  /var/lib/nginx/cache  levels=1:2    keys_zone=STATIC:10m max_size=1G;
proxy_temp_path /var/lib/nginx/proxy 1 2;

server {

location @prerender {
.....................
proxy_cache            STATIC;
proxy_cache_valid      1d; 
if ($prerender = 1) {
rewrite .* /$scheme://$host:$server_port$request_uri? break;
proxy_pass http://10.0.2.2:3000;
}}}
```

Where 10.0.2.2 server with working  prerender.io

And I tried doing this through another nginx, which setup like cache-proxy. In frotnend.conf I comment all caching settings and put them into other nginx. But I still have the same problem, page rendering takes 15sec, and nginx don't make any caching.

**UDP.**

I tried another configuration of nginx, but still have problem.
Schema looks like

```
web-browser(http://myapp.local) > |AppServer(frontend) is a virtual Server|(proxy_pass) > to > |nginx with proxy cache| > to > |prerender|
```

proxy-cache.conf

```
proxy_cache_path  /var/lib/nginx/cache  levels=1:2    keys_zone=STATIC:10m max_size=1G;
proxy_temp_path /var/lib/nginx/proxy 1 2;
server {
..............................
    location / {

            proxy_cache            STATIC;
            proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
            proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires;
            proxy_ignore_headers Expires;
            proxy_cache_methods GET;
            proxy_cache_valid      any  1d; # 200
                    #proxy_cache_key $host$uri$is_args$args;

            proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }}
```

And I configure logging for cache. When I make a request to the server in log I get this:

```
GET /http://myweb.local:80/ HTTP/1.0 "302" 20 "-" "10.0.2.2" "skype" "-" "MISS" "127.0.0.1:3000" "0.388" "0.389"
GET /http://myweb.local:80/en/ HTTP/1.0 "200" 14685 "-" "10.0.2.2" "skype" "-" "MISS" "127.0.0.1:3000" "1.261" "1.263"
GET /http://myweb.local:80/ HTTP/1.0 "302" 20 "-" "10.0.2.2" "skype" "-" "HIT" "-" "-" "0.001"
GET /http://myweb.local:80/en/ HTTP/1.0 "200" 14689 "-" "10.0.2.2" "skype" "-" "MISS" "127.0.0.1:3000" "1.249" "1.251"
```

In log of prerender:

```
2016-06-15T14:05:57.880Z getting http://myweb.local:80/en/
2016-06-15T14:05:59.131Z got 200 in 1251ms for http://myweb.local:80/en/
2016-06-15T14:06:00.332Z getting http://myweb.local:80/en/
2016-06-15T14:06:01.885Z got 200 in 1553ms for http://myweb.local:80/en/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolve this problem. It need to add another ignore of headers **proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;** . So configuration for cache prerender via nginx will be:

```
proxy_cache_path  /var/lib/nginx/cache  levels=1:2    keys_zone=STATIC:10m inactive=24h  max_size=2g;

server {
.......................
location / {
            try_files $uri @prerender;
    }
     location @prerender {
            set $prerender 0;
.......................
            proxy_cache            STATIC;
            proxy_cache_valid    any 1d; 
            proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control;
            proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires;
            proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
            proxy_ignore_headers Expires;
            proxy_cache_key $host$uri$is_args$args;
            proxy_cache_use_stale  error timeout invalid_header updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;

            if ($prerender = 1) {
                    rewrite .* /$scheme://$host:$server_port$request_uri? break;
                    proxy_pass http://10.0.2.2:3000;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly easy to add caching to the prerender server itself, s3 and memory cache works [out of the box](https://github.com/prerender/prerender#s3htmlcache).

If you need need nginx to handle the caching, I think you get a better chance at an answer if you put it in the question title.